# D3 JS not display properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm doing this program for my assignment. Here is my code

```
function init() {
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
    const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date/time
    const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");

    // Set the ranges
    const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the line
    const valueline = d3.line()
      .x(d => x(d.Date))
      .y(d => y(d['High income']));

    // Create the SVG element
    const svg = d3.select("#lineChart")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("../data/CPI.csv").then(data => {

      // Format the data
      data.forEach(d => {
        d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
        d['High income'] = +d['High income'];
      });

      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.Date));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d['High income'])]);

      // Add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

window.onload = init;
```

And here is the output
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wgid.png)

The output is not what I'm looking for. The shape of it is weird. Can anyone please give me solution for the line to be shown properly? Thank you

Comment: I would guess you want to specify `fill: none` for your `path` element. This could be done by adding `.attr("fill", "none")` to the code that creates the path, or by adding `fill: none` to the CSS for the `line` class. Does this help?

Comment: Otherwise close your path according to your diagram width and height by appending these commands to your `d` pathdata attribute  `L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height} Z`